# Javascript check to see is name already exists

Tags: javascript

I am trying to  check if a folder name is unique or not. it works correctly  if I  put in a Name  that  already  exist, but  if  I put in a name that doesn't exist yet  it crashes.

```
// Determines if  the folder's name  is unique
//  @param  {String}  name folder name
 // @return {Boolean} true if unique

function isFolderNameUnique(name) {

  name = name.toLowerCase();

    if(RESERVED_FOLDER_NAMES.indexOf(name) !== -1) {
        return false;
    }
    var i = folders.length;
    while(i--) {
        if(folders[i].name.toLowerCase() === name) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

it crashes at the `if(folders[i].name.toLowerCase()` with

```
TypeError: undefined  is  not a function 'M[r].name.toLowerCase()')
```

Comment: var i = folders.length -1; //?

Comment: @InvernoMuto he is decrementing `i` in the while condition so in the first loop, `i` should actually equal `folders.length - 1`.

Comment: Why don't you check the "folders" list the same way you check "RESERVED_FOLDER_NAMES"? *edit* oh because you may have upper-case in the "folders" list.

Comment: Well in any case the error means that there's an entry in your "folders" list whose "name" property is not a string.

Comment: @Christoph If the operator appears before the variable, the value is modified before the expression is evaluated. If the operator appears after the variable, the value is modified after the expression is evaluated.

Comment: @InvernoMuto You are completely correct. And therefore the loop works just fine :-p

Comment: @InvernoMuto No, in that condition `i` is used to check, if to continue, then the post-decrement is done, then enter the body of the loop. `length-1` would drop the last member of the array out of iteration.

Comment: @InvernoMuto however, if he pre-decremented, he would accidentally drop the first element. In any case, I think we both agree, that it's a rather wacky way to iterate on the array?! ;)

Comment: I think it might help to see how the `folders` array is filled...

Answer (score 1):

I am not if you are using arrays or a combination of array and objects in your full javascript code but here is an alternative solution that works.

Javascript code:(jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/qeyahxy2/5/

```
var functionCall = isFolderNameUnique("one");

//alert results of function call
alert(functionCall);

function isFolderNameUnique(name) {//begin function

  name = name.toLowerCase();

    //if the name is not in the array 
    if(RESERVED_FOLDER_NAMES.indexOf(name) !== -1) {//begin if then else

        //return false
        return false;
    }
    else{

        //return true
        return true;

    }//end if then else

}//end function
```